# "Illegal characters in path" in persian language

Tags: path, character, persian

I use ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll for zip my software file. in file path exist some character contain other language like persian and after zipping file, that turn to ? character an this makes some problem as Illegal characters in path.

```
C:\Program Files\my software\?.zip
```

Now how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `IsUnicodeText` to true for each `ZipEntry`:

```
var newEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName)
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                Size = content.Length,
                IsUnicodeText = true
            };
```